# Yii2, организация переводов, теория

Tags: php, yii2, теория, перевод

Теоретический вопрос по организации переводов. Все тексты переводов будут храниться в файлах, на весь проект их планируется около 2+ тыс.

Есть смысл все переводы сохранять в одном файле app.php и не париться или лучше разбивать по категориям?

Такие варианты рассматриваются:

1. один файл app.php - и все переводы кидаем сюда
2. сделать всего около 3 файлов: app, admin, client
3. на каждую модель - свой файл перевода
4. просто исходя из логики добавлять в нужную категорию

Какой вариант самый оптимальный? Не хочется кашу иметь, а хотелось бы чтобы все переводы были в "чистоте". И чтобы добавление новых текстов не вызывало затруднений от других людей - в какую категорию добавить или лишние проверки на дубли, или добавили текст в одну категорию а в дальнейшем оказалось что такой же текст юзается по логике в другой (или дубль образуется или обращение будет нелогичное)..

Comment: на самом деле "Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях"..........а как мне кажется правильный вариант - один файл на одну сущность.....Есть комментарии - один файл, есть персональная информация юзера - другой файл, личные сообщения - третий  и т.д...... и каждый из них может лежать в своей категории (например перевод о персональных данных юзера в категории Users).... то есть совместить 4 и 3

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд лучше сделать разделение файлов по модулям + 1 глобальный файл. 
В глобальном файле хранить общие для всего проекта переводы, простые и постоянные на всем проекте, например "Да", "Нет" и тд. Разделять файлы по модулям нужно, т.к. одна и та же фраза с одного языка может в другом месте переводится иначе, в зависимости от контекста. Кроме того, не будет помойки переводов в одном файле, и будет проще рефакторить. При удалении модуля лишних переводов не останется.